# Remove duplicates in Numpy array within a panda depending on 2 different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset and want to remove duplicates in x,y. Here I have 3 times (5,7) for the first car. and (4,5) duplicates. I only want to save one of them. I also do not want to do anything with the z column.

I have this:

```
cars = pd.DataFrame({'x': [[1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,7],[4,4,5,6,7,8],[4,4,5,6,7,8]],
                     'y': [[3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,9],[5,5,6,7,8,9],[4,4,5,6,7,8]],
                     'z': [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[5,5,6,7,8,9],[4,4,5,6,7,8]]})
```

I want this:

```
cars = pd.DataFrame({'x': [[1,2,3,4,5,5,7],[4,5,6,7,8],[4,4,5,6,7,8]],
                     'y': [[3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[5,6,7,8,9],[4,4,5,6,7,8]],
                     'z': [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[5,5,6,7,8,9],[4,4,5,6,7,8]]})
```

I have tried this, and it works, only it takes forever.

```
for i in range(len(cars['x'])):
    k= len(cars['x'][i])
    for j in range(k-2):
        if (cars['x'][i][j] == cars['x'][i][j+1]) & (cars['y'][i][j] == cars['y'][i][j+1]):
            cars['x'][i] = np.delete(cars['x'][i], [j + 1])
            cars['y'][i] = np.delete(cars['y'][i], [j + 1])
            k+=1
```

I got some help and this is almost right, only it takes away all duplicates depending only on one column:

```
cars=cars.applymap(lambda x:set(x))
cars=cars.applymap(lambda x:list(x))

cars['x']=cars['x'].apply(lambda x:set(x)).apply(lambda x:list(x))
cars['y']=cars['y'].apply(lambda x:set(x)).apply(lambda x:list(x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update** - faster approach.

```
cars[['x', 'y']] = (
    pd.concat((cars.x.explode(), cars.y.explode()), axis=1)
      .reset_index().drop_duplicates().set_index('index')
      .groupby(level=0).agg(list).agg(np.array)
)
```

```
cars[['x', 'y']] = cars[['x', 'y']].apply(lambda row: 
    list(np.array(list(dict.fromkeys(map(tuple,np.column_stack(row))))).T), 
    axis=1, 
    result_type='expand'
)
```

Comment: Thank you :-), this is a lot faster.